# Sort Dictionary of Array Using Predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have a json dictionary

```
[
  {
    "allquestions": [
      {
        "question": "First question in 0th index"
      },
      {
        "question": "Second  question in 0th index"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "allquestions": [
      {
        "question": "First  question in 1st index"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to get all values of key **allquestions** in single array using predicate.

I have tried so far is

```
NSPredicate *combinePagePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"allquestions == %@",@"someValue"];
```

What will be the value of **someValue** to solve my problem?

Comment: You have an Array of Dictionaries of Arrays of Dictionaries. Somehow I think there's a better way to structure your data.

Comment: @mag_zbc it's get from api service. I have no options to change this structure.

Comment: I don't think a predicate is going to achieve what you want, but there might be other ways - can you clarify exactly what you expect your single array to contain?

Comment: @pbasdf allquestions = @[@"First question in 0th index",@"Second  question in 0th index",First  question in 1st index];

Comment: `NSPredicate` won't do anything. You have to enumerate yourself, or maybe use `valueForKeyPath:`, but I'm not sure it's really faster and simpler. `NSArray *questions = [array valueForKeyPath:@"allquestions.question"]; NSMutableArray *flattenQuestions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [questions enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {[flattenQuestions addObjectsFromArray:obj];}];` So my suggestion: Enumerate the values. It's simpler, easier to debug, and if you need to do a change in 3 months, it's be easier to understand what you did.

Comment: @Larme currently i am doing the same. i was looking for faster way than this.

Comment: A `flatmap` or `map` could gives less code, but I dont think that the enumeration is taking that much time. Also, there is no "sort" int your question, that's misleading.

Comment: @Larme hmm.. i agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your trying to achieve. If you want a list of all of the questions in that dictionary then iterate through each dictionary separately and then the same for the questions. Add the questions to an array and then filter that array. Not tried this code out but it's a start.

```
NSMutableArray *questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
for (id i in dictionaryArray)
{
    NSArray *arr = i[@"allquestions"];
    for (id x in arr) 
    {
       NSString *currentQuestion = [x objectForKey:@"question"];
       [questions addObject:currentQuestion]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to achieve using NSPredicate. Not this way.